# PyCharm's Markdown rendering is beautiful. Is there a way to save it into a pdf or html file as is?

Tags: pycharm, markdown

PyCharm renders Markdown very nicely. It looks awesome. I would like to save the rendered Markdown as PDF or HTML file. When I try to print to PDF or save as HTML, it saves the raw (unrendered) Markdown. I would like to save the rendered Markdown (as PDF or HTML).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure when it was added. But since at most 2021.3, [markdown export](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/markdown.html#export-markdown-file-to-another-format) has been an option.

You will need to have Pandoc installed and configured if PyCharm does not autodetect it already.

One thing to note is that this rendering will occur on a white page, while still using color scheme colors. So you may achieve best results by switching to a light theme before rendering the document.

[image]